# Why is there a need for backup read replica in AWS RDS even though backup on primary is enabled and read replica created using primary server?

Tags: mysql, backup, amazon-rds

In [Working with read replicas - Amazon Relational Database Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ReadRepl.html), it states:

> When creating a read replica, there are a few things to consider. First, you must enable automatic backups on the source DB instance by setting the backup retention period to a value other than 0. This requirement also applies to a read replica that is the source DB instance for another read replica. To enable automatic backups on an RDS for MySQL read replica, first create the read replica, then modify the read replica to enable automatic backups

Why there is need of backup read replica in AWS RDS? What is use of that backup even through there is backup on primary enabled and read replica created using primary server?

I want to know the use of backup taken before creating read replica as read replica created using primary server.

Answer (score 1):

Running a snapshot backup on a live server could slow down a Primary Instance. This is especially true for a Primary Instance running tons of reads and writes.

When you have an I/O-intensive Primary, having a read replica provides you with three(3) major benefits:

- Gives you a warm standby to have to failover from a crashed Primary
- Allow for doing backups that will not impact the Primary
- Allows for SELECT queries away from a busy Primary (provided Seconds_Behind_Master is close to 0)

If you are on a tight budget, doing backups on a live Primary is fine, provided

- you are can live with its performance during the backup period in the middle of the business day
- you made sure backups are scheduled on a Primary during off-peak hours